# The width of the DropDownButton gets increased when adding ButtonTheme

Tags: flutter, drop-down-menu, themes, width, flutter-dropdownbutton

When I use the `ButtonTheme()` to customize the **DropDownMenuItem**, The **DropDownButton** width gets increased. Is this an issue, or am I missing something?

This is my code:

```
SizedBox(
  width: MediaQuery.of(context).size.width * 0.3,
  height: MediaQuery.of(context).size.height * 0.1,
  child: ButtonTheme(
    alignedDropdown: true,
    padding: EdgeInsets.zero,
    child: DropdownButtonFormField<LanguageInfo>(...));
```

Without the `ButtomTheme()` the width of the **DropDownButton** is `width: MediaQuery.of(context).size.width * 0.215,`

I have attached the images for reference. If you see the **edges of the underline** in the DropDownButton, You can see the difference.

With ButtonTheme() :

[image: With ButtonTheme]

Without ButtonTheme() :

[image: Without ButtonTheme]

Comment: try to add `isDense:true` inside dropdown

Comment: It's not working

Comment: try isExpanded = true it will fix your problem hopefully